# POLYLANG: Hide current language

Tags: language

I used below codes to to add a shortcode, and the css to style. Both working fine in [This Website](https://zuleta.com/aa/foundation/):

```
// PHP: Add this to your functions.php file

function polylang_flags_shortcode() {
ob_start();
pll_the_languages(array('show_flags'=>0,'show_names'=>1));
$flags = ob_get_clean();
return '<ul class="polylang-flags">' . $flags . '</ul>';
}
add_shortcode('POLYLANG', 'polylang_flags_shortcode');

/* CSS Polylang Flags/Names Inline */
.polylang-flags {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.polylang-flags li {
    display: inline;   
}
```

Now, I need to hide the current language.

Please advice on a code to add or modify.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the `hide_current` parameter to this function. And when you use plugin function in your code, be sure to check if function exists. If the plugin get disabled, your website will continue to work :)

```
function polylang_flags_shortcode() {
    ob_start();
    if(function_exists('pll_the_languages'))
    {
        echo '<ul class="polylang-flags">';
        pll_the_languages(array(
            'show_flags'    => 0,
            'show_names'    => 1,
            'hide_current'  => 1,
        )); 
        echo '</ul>';
    }
    return ob_get_clean();
}
add_shortcode('POLYLANG', 'polylang_flags_shortcode');
```

I also move the `ul` part !

Comment: sorry to jump in, but how would i get the corresponding translated url? Now it just links to the homepage in the other language ( i just have 2 languages at the moment)

Comment: The Polylang Flag system should gives you translations URL and if there is not, homepage url in other languages. Does it work for you ?